# i get error when build app : app java Pre compile debug

Tags: android-studio, androidx

[image: this is a build.gradle]

[image: this is a build.gradle]

**error**
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$FileCollectionLeafVisitorImpl.visitCollection(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:240)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitLeafCollections(AbstractFileCollection.java:233)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitLeafCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:205)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:126)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskFingerprinter.fingerprintTaskFiles(DefaultTaskFingerprinter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.createExecutionState(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed to transform file 'achartengine-1.2.0.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingArtifactVisitor.lambda$visitFile$3(TransformingArtifactVisitor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingArtifactVisitor.visitFile(TransformingArtifactVisitor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.LocalFileDependencyBackedArtifactSet$SingletonFileResolvedVariant.visit(LocalFileDependencyBackedArtifactSet.java:171)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformCompletion.visit(TransformCompletion.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.CompositeResolvedArtifactSet$CompositeResult.visit(CompositeResolvedArtifactSet.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ParallelResolveArtifactSet$VisitingSet.visit(ParallelResolveArtifactSet.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:256)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$500(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$2.run(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:231)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifactsWithBuildOperation(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$200(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$1.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1167)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Execution failed for JetifyTransform: D:\Project\Pro VPN 2019 Android\Pro VPN 2019 Android\app\libs\achartengine-1.2.0.jar.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$1(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:172)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.mapFailure(Try.java:182)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$2(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:172)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.fireTransformListeners(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$3(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:81)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:90)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:194)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:170)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:194)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:54)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4717)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3444)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2152)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2042)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3850)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4712)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.invoke(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep.lambda$transform$0(TransformationStep.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Success.flatMap(Try.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep.transform(TransformationStep.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationChain.transform(TransformationChain.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationOperation.run(TransformationOperation.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.access$1500(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ParentPreservingQueueWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:444)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runOperation(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.access$600(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:172)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.create(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.create(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:203)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:203)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.run(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:177)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform 'D:\Project\Pro VPN 2019 Android\Pro VPN 2019 Android\app\libs\achartengine-1.2.0.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(from=D:\Project\Pro VPN 2019 Android\Pro VPN 2019 Android\app\libs\achartengine-1.2.0.jar, to=C:\Users\ADMIN.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2b1fbdce24d1dbacf8b58ffc6d7a5aaa\jetified-achartengine-1.2.0.jar)'. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:118)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.LegacyTransformer.transform(LegacyTransformer.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker$TransformerExecution.execute(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:274)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$2(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:148)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(from=D:\Project\Pro VPN 2019 Android\Pro VPN 2019 Android\app\libs\achartengine-1.2.0.jar, to=C:\Users\ADMIN.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2b1fbdce24d1dbacf8b58ffc6d7a5aaa\jetified-achartengine-1.2.0.jar)'
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.loadLibraries(Processor.kt:388)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transform(Processor.kt:241)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:113)
    ... 81 more

Comment: It needs edition and stacktrace format. Please add more details and ask a question to the body

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(from=D:\Project\Pro VPN 2019 Android\Pro VPN 2019 Android\app\libs\achartengine-1.2.0.jar...` Seems like your D drive is missing or you should remove spaces from that filepath for your project

Comment: Besides that, you could just put `compile group: 'org.achartengine', name: 'achartengine', version: '1.2.0'` instead of having that JAR file